# More commands to one output file?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface

I make few commands to parse values from free -m and now need to output all in one file. It looks like this:

```
free -m | grep 'Mem' | awk '{print $3'} && free -m | grep 'Mem' | awk '{print $6'} && free -m | grep 'Mem' | awk '{print $7'} && free -m | grep 'cache:' | awk '{print $3'}
```

if I add > /some/file on end, it write only last value, how to write output from all this commands to one file?
thanks for any help

Comment: You can use several expressions for awk:
E.g. $ free -m | grep 'Mem' | awk '{print $3}{print $6}'   

Or even $ free -m | grep 'Mem' | awk '{print $3"\n"$6}'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add parentheses to open a sub shell:

```
( free -m | grep 'Mem' | awk '{print $3'} && free -m | grep 'Mem' | awk '{print $6'} && free -m | grep 'Mem' | awk '{print $7'} && free -m | grep 'cache:' | awk '{print $3'} ) > result.txt
```

Comment: No need for a subshell.  `{ free -m ... | awk '{print $3'}; } > result.txt` works just fine.  (There's no significant difference, of course: just pointing out an alternative.)

Comment: Thanks - did not know that yet :) One subtle difference is, though, that the subshell approach also works with tcsh, while I get a `{: Command not found.` with your approach. I personally prefer bash, but it's not been clear from the question which shell the OP uses ...